# Disable a html form submit button, to enable with a ticked checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, button, checkbox

I am trying to disable a submit button, and have it be enabled when a checkbox is ticked. Simple example works on jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8YBu5/522/

But not when trying it in my template (with bootstrap etc).

My template has the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="checky"><a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
```

Then the button

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
```

Then the javascript. Does the javascript need to be at the top or something?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit').attr("disabled","disabled");

    $('#checky').click(function(){

        if($(this).attr('checked') == true){
             $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#submit').attr("disabled","disabled");   

        }
    });
    </script>
```

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
Thanks for all the suggestions, I've now tried adding the `$(document).ready(function() {` to the start of my script and changed `.attr` to `.prop` , still not working. Little more info: The button isn't disabled from the start, so maybe I'm not referencing the button properly in the function?

**UPDATE2**
I've tried adding an alert to see if my javascript is being run, but the alert doesn't show, what could this mean?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    alert("Welcome");
    $('submit').prop("disabled", true);
    $('checky').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr('checked') == true){
            $('submit').prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            $('submit').prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE3** The javascript is now running, I've added two alerts, to see what is executing.

```
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#postme').attr("disabled","disabled");

$('#checky').click(function(){

    if($(this).attr('checked') == true){
        alert( "w" );   
         $('#postme').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else {
      alert( "e" );   
        $('#postme').attr("disabled","disabled");   

    }
});
});//]]>
```

When I click the checkbox on or off, I get the e alert, telling me the if statement is always false. Any ideas why?

**UPDATE4**
The snippet works, just not in my page, alert 2 is always executed, never alert 1
    
    
    
      Title

```
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">


        <div class="row padding">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1></h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row padding">

            <form id="new_form" action="/page/" method="POST" >

              <div class="panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="col-md-12"> 

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

              <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Creator submission form</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="col-md-12"> 

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <br>

               <input type="checkbox"  id="checky1">
               <input type="submit" id="postme1" value="submit">

                        </form>
        </div>

        <div class="row padding">
            <div class="col-md-12">

            </div>
        </div>              
    </div>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#postme1').attr("disabled","disabled");

$('#checky1').click(function(){

    if($(this).attr('checked') == true){
         $('#postme1').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#postme1').attr("disabled","disabled");   
    }
});
});//]]>  

</script>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <footer>
  <hr>

  </footer>
</div>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#postme1').attr("disabled","disabled");

$('#checky1').click(function(){

    if($(this).attr('checked') == true){
      alert("1");
         $('#postme1').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
      alert("2");
        $('#postme1').attr("disabled","disabled");   

    }
});
});//]]>  

</script>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { ....your JQuery... });` - http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/#launching-code-on-document-ready

Comment: You should also be using `prop` rather than `attr` -- `.prop("disabled", true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your javascript code should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#postme').attr("disabled","disabled");

$('#checky').click(function(){

    if($(this).attr('checked') == true){
         $('#postme').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#postme').attr("disabled","disabled");   

    }
});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox"  id="checky"><a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
<input type="submit" id="postme" value="submit">

</body>


</html>
```

This snippet is working fine for me.

**Update**

Use this as click event handler of the checkbox

```
$('#checky').click(function(){

    if($(this).prop('checked')){
         $('#postme').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#postme').attr("disabled","disabled");   

    }
});
```

Comment: Putting the <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>   before my script did the job. Thanks

Comment: sorry false alarm, the button is now greyed out, but doesn't enable when the checkbox is checked

Comment: @user1608058: are you trying to use the above snippet offline?

Comment: @user1608058 :: I've uploaded the above snippet to my server. check this link. http://productdemos.net/test.html

Comment: this snippet works, its just putting it into the rest of the page, it doesn't. The checkbox and submit button are inside a form, would this cause a problem? Only other thing I can think of is django is causing problems, but unlikely as when i put in alerts to the if-else they appear, just that it always evaluates as false

Comment: @user1608058 :: can you post your rendered html from your `browser->view source`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46275/discussion-between-krishanu-dey-and-user1608058)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46295/discussion-between-krishanu-dey-and-holmeswatson)

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle is a lovely resource. One of the lovely things it does is provide the wrapper for JQuery for you!

[Have a little read of this](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/#launching-code-on-document-ready):

> **Launching Code on Document Ready**
>
> To ensure that their code runs after the browser finishes loading the document, many JavaScript programmers wrap their code in an onload function:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert( "welcome" );     
}
```

> Unfortunately, the code doesn't run until all images are finished downloading, including banner ads. To run code as soon as the document is ready to be manipulated, jQuery has a statement known as the ready event:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Your code here.     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your include your `<script>` *after* the rest of your html. Or you can wrap it in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Also you should use `.change` instead of `.click`, in case the user uses the keyboard to check the checkbox.

Comment: Check/Uncheck using keyboard also fires `.click`.